# Check if keyword exists in a JSON response - Azure Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

In my Azure Logic App, I have an action to get rows from SQL database as follows.

[image]

And sample output (body) of this as follows,

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://logic-apis-southeastasia.azure-apim.net/apim/sql/5bb78f1b756e4b6097a8bccb6be8dae7/$metadata#datasets('virtueagintegrationssqldbsv-dev2.database.windows.net%2CLearnIntegrationDB-dev2')/tables('%5Bdbo%5D.%5BLearnEmployeeExamData%5D')/items",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "ddf29856-4452-4511-a041-83a4bcf3e8fc",
      "EXAMSTART": "YES",
      "EXAMRESULT": "YES"
    },
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "b5a0261b-c5bf-4f14-8a87-a6acd3aaa26b",
      "EXAMSTART": "YES",
      "EXAMRESULT": "YES"
    },
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "7035458b-605d-431e-a352-dc91261f2a59"
    },
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "648d4c06-c3e0-45a9-b656-1aab485d12fd"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there expression to check at least one item has `"EXAMSTART": "YES"` from the item list "values" as shown in above response??

Ex: For above response it should output `True` as it's having two such items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Data Operations**-> **Filter Array** step to get only those items with `EXAMSTART: "YES"`:

[image]
[image]

[image]

and then use [length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#length) to evaluate whether there's any array item returned from `Filter Array`:

[image]

code view:

```
"Condition": {
    "actions": {},
    "expression": {
        "and": [
            {
                "greater": [
                    "@length(body('Filter_array'))",
                    0
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "Filter_array": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "If"
},
"Filter_array": {
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@body('Get_rows_(V2)')?['value']",
        "where": "@equals(item()?['EXAMSTART'], 'YES')"
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "Get_rows_(V2)": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "Query"
},
```